# How to compare strings with multiple line

Tags: c#, string, comparison

I have a method which is generating the following, which i am saving in a string, lets say that string is name `output`

```
HDRPB509030978SENTRIC MUSIC                                01.102013070914290620130709               
GRHREV0000102.100000000000  
REV0000000000000000AWAITING YOUR CALL                                          EN00000000044021                               POP000436Y      ORI         PHIL 
TRL000010000000100000022
```

what i am trying is to hard code the above line and compare it to the generated output. I am hard-coding like this i am replacing the next lines with \n like this

```
string hardCoded = "    HDRPB509030978SENTRIC MUSIC                              \n01.102013070914290620130709                   \n    GRHREV0000102.100000000000      \n    REV0000000000000000AWAITING YOUR CALL                                          \nEN00000000044021                               POP000436Y      ORI         PHIL     \n    TRL000010000000100000022   "
```

now when i compare

```
output == hardCoded
```

OR

```
Assert.AreEqual(output,hardCoded);
```

is is false. how to compare these two

Comment: you need the whitespaces to be equals? if not the easiest solution that come to my mind is to make the equality check on trimmed string. otherwise use the debugger, break when you have the string to copy the exact string from the debugger environment

Comment: can u just replace \n with \r\n and try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparing multi-line strings is not different from comparing single-line strings: the strings you compare must match character-for-character, including whitespace and line breaks. If your generated string uses `\r\n` separator instead of `\n`, then the string constant that you expect to get must contain the same separator as well. You can check the kind of separators that you use by setting a breakpoint, and examining the string that you generate in a debugger.

Rather than hard-coding the string for unit testing, consider reading it from a resource. This would let you edit the string in a text editor, and inspect it visually for differences.

Finally, if you do not need the whitespace to match, you could define a function that compares strings excluding whitespace:

```
static bool EqualsExcludingWhitespace(String a, String b) {
    return a.Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
       .SequenceEqual(b.Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c)));
}
```

Comment: @JunaidSaeed Then you need to either check the separators and whitespace, or ignore them using the comparator suggested in my edit.